# Why does C++ not allow passing a void argument to a function having zero parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, language-lawyer, void

```
void f()
{}

void f(int)
{
    return f(); // #1: ok
}

void g(auto fn)
{
    f(fn());
}

int g1()
{
    return 0;
}

void g2()
{}

int main()
{
    g(g1); // #2: ok
    g(g2); // #3: error
}
```

C++ allows *explicitly returning a void value* as shown at `#1`, I think it's elegant and generic.

However, the rule cannot be applied to `#3` in the same way.

**Why does C++ not allow passing a void argument to a function having zero parameters?**

Comment: C++ does not necessarily have a reason for preventing this, but if there is a reason, then I suppose it may be because allowing it could lead to some mighty confusing situations.  Then again, there already exist so many confusing things about this language, I doubt one more would make a difference.  So, congratulations, you found a shortcoming of the language worth ranting about.

Comment: This would significantly complicate templates and template metaprogramming and probably break a lot of existing code. Macros that used `__VA_NARG__` would also break if any of the arguments were forwarded as function parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the language specifies that each argument expression in the call initialises a parameter of the function

[`[expr.call/7]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.call#7)

> When a function is called, each parameter is initialized with its corresponding argument.

In a function of no parameters, there is no first parameter to initialise, and even if there were, `void` is a type with no values.